# widgets stick with each other tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

Im using Tkinter framework to build a log in page but when i use the grid method to place entries and buttons inside a frame i got the login text and its entry in the same row ,same thing for the password and its entries in other row , that's sounds good but the problem is they look sticky even if i gave a big difference to the row option

the distance between log in and pwd still the same .

[you can get what i mean by looking at this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buXv2.png)

```
logbox = LabelFrame(root, text="Log In", font=("Corbel"),
                    highlightbackground=darg, highlightcolor=darg, highlightthickness=5, bg=darg, height=300, width=300)

logbox.grid_propagate(0)
logbox.pack(side=TOP)
tuser = Label(logbox, text="CIN", bg=darg, font=("arial", 9), fg="white")
y = 20
tuser.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=y)
enuser = ttk.Entry(logbox,)
enuser.grid(row=0, column=2, pady=y)

tpwd = Label(logbox, text="Password", bg=darg, font=("arial", 9), fg="white")
tpwd.grid(row=4, column=1)
enpwd = ttk.Entry(logbox,)
enpwd.grid(row=4, column=2)
logbut = ttk.Button(logbox, text="Log In", width=20)
logbut.grid(row=15, column=3,)
```

I've tried using the pady method , it kinda work but it's just like a temporary solution , I want to understand why the widgets are sticky.

Comment: rows and columns without widget will have default size 0.  I don't think that using `padx` and `pady` is a temporary solution.

Comment: @acw1668  ty but is there a way to set the default value of rows and column different than 0

Comment: Use `logbox.rowconfigure(list(range(15)), minsize=x)` where x is the desired value you want.  Similar for `logbox.columnconfigure(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand color `darg`. You messed up `row=4` and `row=15`. You can used `pady`. The easier way to do this.

Here is code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

logbox = LabelFrame(root, text="Log In", font=("Corbel"),
                    highlightbackground='red', highlightcolor='red', highlightthickness=5, bg='red', height=300, width=300)

logbox.grid_propagate(0)
logbox.pack(side=TOP)

tuser = Label(logbox, text="CIN", bg='red', font=("arial", 9), fg="white")
tuser.grid(row=0, column=1)

enuser = ttk.Entry(logbox,)
enuser.grid(row=0, column=2)

tpwd = Label(logbox, text="Password", bg='red', font=("arial", 9), fg="white")
tpwd.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=5)

enpwd = ttk.Entry(logbox,)
enpwd.grid(row=1, column=2, pady=5)

logbut = ttk.Button(logbox, text="Log In", width=20)
logbut.grid(row=2, column=2, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]